# Trying to kill a process by NAME and CPU Time

Tags: powershell, cmd, explorer

What I'm trying is to close a windows of explorer.exe without killing the whole process, because that will restart the whole taskbar. So far I can only identify it by CPU Time which separated from the windows explorer.exe because it start after.

Is there a PowerShell script or command out there that could help me achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a closer look at the Shell.Application COM Object.
The method 'Windows()' returns an object foreach open explorer-window.
You can call the the method 'Quit()' of these Objects to close the windows, here is a example:

```
$explorerPathYouWantToKill = "C:\"

$shellApp = New-Object -COM 'Shell.Application'
($shellApp.Windows() | Where-Object {$_.LocationURL -eq "file:///$($explorerPathYouWantToKill.Replace('\','/'))"}) | Foreach {
    $_.Quit()
}
```